# How to implement Firebase User Meta Data in order to know whether the user is existing or new one

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have already checked firebase documentation on how to use `FirebaseUserMetaData` interface so I have tried but things didnot worked for me, So anybody knows how to implement this code

```
FirebaseUserMetadata metadata = auth.getCurrentUser().getMetadata();
if (metadata.getCreationTimestamp() == metadata.getLastSignInTimestamp()) {
    // The user is new, show them a fancy intro screen!
} else {
    // This is an existing user, show them a welcome back screen.
}
```

**Also cant find auth.getCurrentUser().getMetadata()**

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Cannot resolve this code at all no lib smth like that

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is part of a separate android library called FireBase-UI.

You need to import that dependency to use that method. The details and source for that are below:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

The exact library you are using is here:

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md

```
dependencies {
// ...
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.1.2'

// Required only if Facebook login support is required

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.x'

// Required only if Twitter login support is required

implementation("com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.x@aar") { transitive = true }
}
```

Also make sure that the auth object exists first:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
FirebaseUserMetadata metadata = auth.getCurrentUser().getMetadata();
    if (metadata.getCreationTimestamp() == metadata.getLastSignInTimestamp()) {
        // Do your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: am sorry what exactly should i import from that library be specific

Comment: I have already seen and implemented this library in my project

Comment: They are listed here: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md

Comment: I know I have used this library. When it comes to this peace of code it is not working

Comment: Yes it is authenticated everything works fine. But i need to know whether user is already signed up for my app or new one

Comment: Got it. You have had multiple questions and I didn't understand what you were asking initially. I don't know the answer, but suggest checking the example on the repo and/or asking on the repository issues too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this on sign in/up.
The AuthResult will contain additional user info: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AuthResult.html#getAdditionalUserInfo()

Additional user info contains a getter `isNewUser`:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo.html#isNewUser()

Comment: But I am using phone auth :)

Comment: What I really wanna know is that the user is existing one or new user )

Comment: It doesn't matter. This solution still works. Phone authentication sign in flow still returns an AuthResult.

Comment: Okay let me try it ty))